# Is it possible to add Offset in NavigationView android?

Tags: android, navigationview

I use NavigationView to create a Left slide menu. But i want the menu remain in Left position on few px (100-150dp) . I've try to play with margin, padding, searching google sample code, but no results.

There's a solution ?

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

try this...set width of your navigation

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/back_color"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"/>
```

Comment: It's not working, because, width define how large is the menu when expanded.

Comment: you cant do that..as per android documentation drawer is used to pulled out...and why you need this?

Comment: Damned, i want do this only for esthetic, and to show user there's a left menu

Comment: for that use nav. icon in your actionbar. user will get idea by it